# An error occurred while installing byebug (5.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, byebug

Here are my program versions:

Ruby 2.2.2p95

Rails 4.2.3

```
Installing byebug 5.0.0 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150719-7912-f08j1k.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
generating byebug-x64-mingw32.def
compiling breakpoint.c
In file included from c:/Ruby22-x64/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:29:0,
                 from c:/Ruby22-x64/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./byebug.h:4,
                 from breakpoint.c:1:
c:/Ruby22-x64/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/defines.h:65:22: fatal error: setjmpex.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [breakpoint.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/byebug-5.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/byebug-5.0.0/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing byebug (5.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '5.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: How did you install this ruby? It looks like it doesnt have the include files required for compiling native extensions included with it.

Comment: I downloaded Ruby, Rails, and the DevKit from railsinstaller.org. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I wont be able to give specific help with it, but did you follow ALL the instructions [here](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit)?

Comment: edit: I did follow those instructions and everything seemed to install fine. Reading the rest of the page there might be a whitespace in the folder name issue. Let me try something.

Comment: I'd just make sure I hadn't missed some important step in those instructions before I uninstalled and reinstalled. Good luck!