# Failed to build byebug native gem extension

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, byebug

I literally looked everywhere and couldnt find an answer to it. I installed ruby on my windows with the installer they proviude on their website. Yes, i am running it on a 64 bit which is what my devkit is on. idk what to do i literally looke everywehreeeee someone please help!!!

```
    ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x64-mingw32]

C:\Users\ASUS>gem install byebug
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing byebug:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/byebug-11.0.0/ext/byebug
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20190314-10812-4pefs.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/byebug-11.0.0/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/byebug-11.0.0/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR="
generating byebug-x64-mingw32.def
compiling breakpoint.c
In file included from c:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/ruby.h:29:0,
                 from c:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from byebug.h:4,
                 from breakpoint.c:1:
c:/Ruby25-x64/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/defines.h:151:22: fatal error: setjmpex.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [breakpoint.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/byebug-11.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/byebug-11.0.0/gem_make.out
```

Comment: When the system refuses to post your question because the exact same title is already in use on another question, don't just prepend it with `RUBY | ` and think that makes it good to go. Make your title SPECIFIC TO YOUR QUESTION, not more generic!

Comment: @anothermh this is the first time that i am ever using stack overflow so excuse me if i didnt get it right, but do you know the answer to the problem?

Comment: I googled your error message and [read the first result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506814/an-error-occurred-while-installing-byebug-5-0-0-and-bundler-cannot-continue) -- it seems someone else had this exact issue, due to installing the 32-bit *devkit*, instead of the 64-bit. Are you certain this is all installed correctly?

Comment: @TomLord hi tom thanks for responding! yes i checked everything out on google i did install the devkit as instructed online and it was combined with the ruby 2.5.3 installer that they posted on their website. is there a way i can check for sure which one is installed? also those threads that others posted with the same issue seem to be outdated and from years ago.. im a bit confused haha